# Get id of item push to array in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

*Post Schema, Comment Schema*

```
const commentSchema = new schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

const postSchema = new schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    timeCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
    comments: [commentSchema],
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

I push comment to array `comments` in Post by using

```
const newPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, {
            $push: {
                comments: {
                    content,
                },
            },
        });
```

I want to the get the id of new comment, but when I `console.log` it return the Post which not updated. I use postman and see that new comment has been pushed to my post. How can I get the id of new comment ?

Comment: my suggestion, its better to generate comment id separately and push with comment, using `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idea by **@turivishal** : create id comment and push it

```
const commentId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, {
            $push: {
                comments: {
                    _id: commentId
                    content,
                },
            },
        });
```

It solved my problem. But welcome any other solution